# Ruby doesn't show button on tag button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I'm reading a guide on ruby on rails "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" and i'm running on my computer Ruby 1.9.3

In the interaxtion 9.3 I'm trying to create a button for creating a LineItem with the tag button_to

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(product_id: product) %>
```

but when i try to execute the code in localhost the button doesn't appear.

Is there a code variation of this tag in Ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: It's rails method, so it's no difference if you're running Ruby 2.x or 1.9.3. Check what HTML is being generated.

Comment: Without more context it's hard to know, but try removing the `product_id:`, making it `<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_item_path(product) %>` and see what happens. Although, I would assume you should be passing line_item_path a 'line_item'...?

Comment: The code you pasted works. So most likely the problem is elsewhere on the page. Try updating your question with the rest of the code on the page. My guess is that you have another element on the page that wasn't closed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with your syntax:

```
<%= button_to raw("<i class=\"icon-search icon-white\">Add To Cart</i>"), 
          line_items_path(product_id: product), 
          class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

Enclose the label of the button in double quotes, escape the double quotes in your i tag, and finally, wrap everything into a raw() call to ensure the HTML is properly displayed.

Alternatively you can use html_safe:

```
<%= button_to "<i class=\"icon-search icon-white\">Add To Cart</i>".html_safe, 
          line_items_path(product_id: product), 
          class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

Comment: i don't think is an error of syntax i've tryed your code but it doesn't produce the html when i execute it

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need the form-creating functionality proivided by button_to helper, you might want to use either link_to or button_tag both of which take blocks.

```
<%=button_tag class: "btn btn-success" do %>
  <i class="icon-search icon-white">Add to Cart </i> 
<%end%>

<%=link_to products_path, class: "btn btn-success" do %>
  <i class="icon-search icon-white">Add to Cart &nbsp;</i> 
<%end%>
```

Hope that helps.